# how to prevent tinymce from stripping empty tags from input?

Tags: tinymce

I have read loads of posts on various forums and here on SO, and still seem unable to prevent tinymce from stripping empty  tags from the end of an editable block.

E.g. I input this:

```
<a href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer" style=""></div>
```

..and upon round trip (in and out of HTML mode), tinymce strips off the entire `<div class="floatClearer" style=""></div>`.

As per various bits of advise I found, I tried these things, and more:

- remove the minus sign in front of `div` in my `valid_elements`,

...and these config. options:

- `verify_html : false,`
- `extended_valid_elements : "div*",`
- `extended_valid_elements : "div[*]",`

ALL to no avail.  is there any way to prevent that stripping action?  There are other places I need empty tags (not just in this one example), so please, if you can, let me know an answer specific to my question, as opposed to suggesting I not use empty tags.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle with your configuration to help us getting a betterinsight to your problem? see http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: welcome back :-), and thanks.  
Sure, here, this demos the issue well:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/j9baab/1   
Tinymce, fiddles, SO..  what an amazing time to be a coder, with all these incredible tools!

Comment: using your tinymce fiddle i cannot see how your empty div gets stripped out (i inserted above div using the 'html'-button of the codeplugin)

Comment: really?  I don't understand what you and I are doing differently.  I go here:  
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/j9baab/1  
...and input this exact string:  `aaaaaaaa
<a href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer" style=""></div>` into the tinymce textarea *while in HTML mode*... hit the 'update' button, and then go back into HTML mode, and see the `<div...</div>` is gone.

Comment: if i open up the html-view a second time i cannot see the empty div, but this might be due to the fact that the html-view does not show everything that is in the editor iframe (like tinymce bookmark-nodes (spans)) even though it is there

Comment: hmm..
Yes, I see now for the first time the behavior you mention, that:
"html-view does not show everything that is in the editor iframe" 

but.. please bear with me.. 

if I input this into tinymce (HTML mode):
`<a href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer"></div>
<a href="blah">zzz</a>`
...and hit the 'update' button 

...and then 'inspect element' on that content, I see it has become this in the editor iframe:
`<a href="blah" data-mce-href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer"><br></div>
<a href="blah" data-mce-href="blah">zzz</a>` 

(more in next comment)

Comment: ...and upon form submit, this is what the form actually passes:
`<a href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer"></div>
<a href="blah">zzz</a>` 

BUT 

if I input this into tinymce (HTML mode):
`<a href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer"></div>`
...and hit the 'update' button 

...and then 'inspect element' on that content, I see it has become this in the editor iframe:
`<a href="blah" data-mce-href="blah">zzz</a>
<div class="floatClearer"><br></div>` 

... so far so good... 

**but** upon form submit, this is what the form actually passes:
`<a href="blah">zzz</a>`

Comment: @Thariama can you confirm the behavior described in my last 2 comments?  AFAICT tinymce does finally at some point strip the empty element when it is the last element in the input, despite that it is viewable in the editor iframe while 'inspecting element', before form submit.  I am a little confused about *when* the empty element is being stripped, but am pretty sure I have eliminated other culprits (besides tinymce) as possible causes of stripping the trailing empty element.

Comment: yes, i can confirm this behavior. actually i am not that sure which setting forces the tinymce cleanup process to eliminate your empty div

Comment: that makes it kinda hard to fix  ;-)  But it is nice to think that it is even controllable via a 'setting', and so just a matter of figuring out which config. option is the culprit.  Are you sure it *is* even possible to prevent tinymce from stripping empty tags (in the case I describe in these comments), *via any amount* of fiddling with the config.?

Comment: i think this should be possible

Comment: I asked in the tinymce forum directly, because i thought that this config usually shouldn't strip out the divs. Spocke (the tinymce chief developer) confirmed this and asked me to file a bug report which i did. The question and answer can be found here:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=101363#p101363 The bug report is here: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5269

Comment: thanks Thariama!  I did not have the knowledge of tinymce's internals to know that that was the appropriate course of action to pursue here, versus fiddling more with config.  So it is a great help that you did pursue it and confirmed the state of things, saving any confusion/time.  With any luck, I just subscribed to that tinymce thread and bug report.

Comment: that is a good idea here - you will get informed about the fix

Comment: fixed in tinymce v. 3.5.2  http://www.tinymce.com/develop/changelog/?ctrl=version&act=view&pr_id=1&vr_id=618

Comment: It's spocke , not Spoky :)

Comment: @ysrb: corrected :)

Comment: verify_html : false, worked for me :)

Comment: If this is 'fixed', why do I still run into this all the time. See, my answer below.

Answer (score 24):

There was a bug in TinyMCE, and now it's fixed (in v3.5.2). Thanks to [@Thariama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama)!

For future searchers: Use the [`verify_html`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html) option.

> This option enables or disables the element cleanup functionality. If you set this option to false, all element cleanup will be skipped but other cleanup functionality such as URL conversion will still be executed.
>
> Example of usage:
>
> ```
> tinyMCE.init({
>     ...
>     verify_html: false
> });
> ```

Comment: doesn't this allow <script> doEvilThings(); </script> tags too, though?

Comment: @RichC good question, but I don't know the answer. you may want to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question. or research this topic yourself and share your findings with the Stack Overflow community. I just know that this type of "evil things" is called XSS vulnerability. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side scripts into web pages viewed by other users.

Comment: I tested it and it left in script tags so I wouldn't recommend any of the answers on this page.

Comment: @RichC could you tell what cases did you test? a) is `<script>` tag filtered out with `verify_html: true`? b) is `<script>` tag filtered out with `verify_html: false`? c) is `<script>` tag filtered out if you don't specify `verify_html`?

Comment: Yes, filtered out with verify_html: true and isn't filtered out with verify_html: false

Answer (score 4):

As I do too have troubles, I am adding my brick - on top of Cliff Ribaudo answer.

So I recommend using `&nbsp;` inside the empty tag which won't be stripped and won't be visible, not even by search engines.

Doing like so have not been stripped on my tinyMCE: `<div class="someclass">&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sticking this here because I'm ***still*** bumping into this issue ***ALL*** the time on WordPress blogs (even now, 2016) where I need to use empty divs to insert **Google Analytics,  Google Translate** and **Google Tag Manager**.

The typical pattern is you add one someplace on a blog page where you need it and the next time you come back and touch the page with the TinyMCE editor whammo, bammo your divs gone!

The ***ONLY*** thing I've found that seems to always work reliably is something like the following:

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="text-align:right;"><span style="display:none;">ha_ha_I_beat_u_tinyMCE</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    extended_valid_elements: 'span[*]'
});
```

I'm using TinyMCE 5.5 and this example above does NOT stop TinyMCE from stripping **empty** span tags for me. I'm using a workaround that is better than nothing of putting a comment inside the span tags to prevent TinyMCE stripping,  I have done it like this so I can include fontawesome icons:

```
<span class="fas fa-check-circle"><!--icon--></span>
```

I think you can turn off all html validation/editing in TinyMCE like this, but I wasn't comfortable with this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    extended_valid_elements: 'span[*]'
});
```

I'm using TinyMCE 5.5 and this example above does NOT stop TinyMCE from stripping empty span tags for me. I'm using a workaround that is better than nothing of putting a comment inside the span tags to prevent stripping,  I have done it like this so I can include font awesome icons:

```
<span class="fas fa-check-circle"><!--icon--></span>
```

I think you can turn off all HTML validation/editing in TinyMCE with this settings, but I wasn't comfortable with it:

```
verify_html: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was to be extreme and extend the valid elements to accept ALL, might not be ideal but client is happy

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
     $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent from removing a specific empty tag, use option `extended_valid_elements`.

Example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    extended_valid_elements: 'span[*]'
});
```